# Protractor selector using blocker

Tags: jquery, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a list that used to show different kinds of profile status.
The status maybe like passed, failed, attention, reading and so on.

In Chrome inspector, I could use Jquery syntax to locate the list.

```
$('div > div > li > div:has(span.passed, span.failed, span.attention, span.reading)')
```

and the length is correct.
But in Protractor spec, I tried to use the same, It always report error.
What I write in the protractor below:

```
element.all(by.css('div > div > li > div:has(span.passed, span.failed, span.attention, span.reading)')).count().then(function (count) {
      console.log(count);
});
```

Can someone help to answer what is the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting on running this?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal, it prompts something like  "- Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified..."

Answer (score 0):

Using '$' has a different meaning in console and in Protractor.

When you use '$' in console - you are using jQuery.
In protractor it has a different meaning - it is 'by.css' (has you tried to use).

You could try using xpath maybe or 'by.css' differently.

Comment: Thanks. That what I did to use by.css() in Protractor to instead $ in JQuery console. But seems like the ":has" is not good support with by.css().  I am trying to use by.xpath to handle it